# vue-router : failed to resolve async component render

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-router

I am a beginner to vue-router and I can't make it work. When I start my app, I get the following errors :

```
[vue-router] Failed to resolve async component render: TypeError: _vm is undefined
49:16:39
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
49:16:39
TypeError: _vm is undefined
Stack trace:
render@webpack-internal:///63:3:7
resolveAsyncComponents/</<@webpack-internal:///49:1774:17
flatMapComponents/</<@webpack-internal:///49:1801:66
...
```

Here are my files : main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './routes.js'
import 'bootstrap'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

routes.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from './Home.vue'

export const routes = [
  { name: 'Home', path: '', components: Home }
]

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Show `App.vue`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a typo in `routes`, change components to component:

```
export const routes = [
  { name: 'Home', path: '', component: Home }
]
```